# How to implement GPS for Windows Phone

Tags: windows, azure

I new to Windows Phone development. I need to information how to enable GPS feature in Windows Phone 8. I need to location point on MAPs

-Mahender

Answer (score 1):

With Windows Phone 8, you can create applications that utilize the phone’s physical location. Scenarios for location-aware applications include checking the user into a web service using the user’s instantaneous location and tracking the user’s location as it changes over a period of time. The location data the phone provides comes from multiple sources including GPS, Wi-Fi, and cellular. There are two different sets of APIs that can be used to incorporate location data into your application. This topic will help you decide which location API is right for your application.
The Windows Phone Runtime Location API

**The Windows Phone Runtime location API is new in Windows Phone 8. It has the following features:**

Accessible from managed and native code. If you are writing a Direct3D app application, you must use this API for location. If you are creating a managed app, it is recommended that you use this API as well.

When tracking location, apps can request to receive location updates after a specified time interval or after the device has moved at least a specified distance from the previous location.

Convergent with Windows 8. Although there are minor differences between the two platforms, this API will allow you to reuse most of your location code if you are targeting both the phone and the desktop.

For information on using the Windows Phone Runtime location API in your application, see the following topics.

```
How to get the phone's current location for Windows Phone 8
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206956(v=vs.105).aspx

```
How to continuously track the phone's location for Windows Phone 8
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj247548(v=vs.105).aspx

```
How to run location-tracking apps in the background for Windows Phone 8
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935(v=vs.105).aspx

To download a sample app that demonstrates getting the phone’s current location, tracking the phone’s location, and tracking location in the background, see Location Sample for Windows Phone 8.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431800%28v=vs.105%29.aspx